# Como cerrar la ventana de imprimir de windows

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

estoy intentando automatizar un cierre de imprimir de windows, el problema es que cuando pulso el botón de imprimir y me abre la ventana de imprimir, no me permite cerrarla, tampoco reconce ningún xpath. Supongo que será un plugin o algo para controlar este tipo pantalla. Os paso la pantalla que quiero que cierre:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías mostrar el código que maneja esa parte en específico?